# How to install specific mysql 5.6.21 version on redhat?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, mysql

My requirement is Mysql 5.6.21. I tried to install Mysql but it installed 5.6.31 version.

I tried following steps:

`$ yum repolist all | grep mysql`

It gives following output:

```
mysql55-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.5 Community Server      disabled
mysql55-community-source          MySQL 5.5 Community Server - So disabled
mysql56-community/x86_64          MySQL 5.6 Community Server      enabled:   
mysql56-community-source          MySQL 5.6 Community Server - So disabled
```

Then I run

`$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server mysql-community-client`

```
Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.el7 will be installed  

Processing Dependency: mysql-community-client(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.el7 for package: mysql-community-server-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64
Running transaction check
Package MySQL-client.x86_64 0:5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5 will be obsoleted
Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.el7 will be obsoleting
Finished Dependency Resolution
```

It installs Mysql 5.6.31. Could any one help me to install Mysql 5.6.21?

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.2 64bit Version.

Comment: Why do you need to install that specific version?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to `https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/` then download after selecting respective version Like: **5.6.21** and OS platform Like **Redhat enterprise Linux/oracle linux** . then you can install using rpm.

Comment: I downloaded Mysql 5.6.21 binary from mysql repository. Could you please suggest the process to setup it.

Comment: The corresponding How-To for installing 5.6.x from RPM can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-rpm.html Note that attempting to install `-server-5.6.*` and `-server-minimal-5.6.*` from the rpm-bundle will conflict and you will have to exclude one.

Answer (score 0):

If the `repository` has got no `rpm`s for the specific version you need, one could try downloading the specific `rpm` through any of the numerous repositories readily available on the web and then use the rpm manager to install it as,

```
rpm -ivh packagename.rpm
```

Comment: packagename means **_MySQL-server-5.6.21-1.linux_glibc2.5.i386.rpm_** ? am i right? Could you please specify. I downloaded rpm bundle from mysql and tried to run by **rpm -ivh**. I got error.

Comment: What error was that? The `yum` usage is preferable as it takes care of the probable dependencies, If the `rpm` package is bundled with all of it's dependencies then there shouldn't have been a glitch, also these packages are distribution specific, which goes without saying

Comment: I installed Mysql-Server and client. Is there any other package installation and configuration required? When i tried to run service it gives The server **quit without updating PID file (/[FAILED]l/mysql/data/oc2838762211.ibm.com.pid)**